# Why is the attribute style not being added to the img?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://ru.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">
</div>
```

```
function moveBall(event){
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
    let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
    ball.style.left = x
    ball.style.top = y
}

let field = document.getElementById('field');
field.onclick = moveBall
```

I was expecting a `style` attribute with value `left=...` to be added to the `<img>` tag. It is works with `<div>` but not with `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. First, `x` and `y` will need units. Second, you need to define a position for the ball, e.g. `relative`:

```js
function moveBall(event) {
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
  let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
  ball.style.left = x + 'px';
  ball.style.top = y + 'px';
}

let field = document.getElementById('field');
field.onclick = moveBall
```

```css
#ball {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://ru.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this css code.

```
#field img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
}

#field {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Also change the javascript code like this.

```
ball.style.left = x + 'px'
ball.style.top = y  + 'px'
```

Full code (This is working well)

html

```
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://ru.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#field img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
}

#field {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Javascript

```
function moveBall(event){
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
    let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
    ball.style.left = x + 'px'
    ball.style.top = y  + 'px'
}

let field = document.getElementById('field');
field.onclick = moveBall
```